# How to retrieve Amazon EC2 Password?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created an Amazon EC2 instance. I have got the password file and it was lost. How to login now without the password ? Is there any way to create a new login ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't once you deleted your private key file and if you don't have a copy of it then you have no way of logging in.  You can try this assuming it's an EBS backed instance:

1. Stop your EC2 instance
2. Detach your root Volume (/dev/sda1) -- Assuming this is `Volume A`
3. Spin up a new EC2 instance of the same type.
4. Attach `Volume A` to that new instance as `/dev/sdf`
5. ssh connect to his new instance.
6. `mkdir -p /mnt/xvdf`
7. `mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/xvdf`
8. `cp ~/.ssh to /mnt/xvdf/home//.
9. `chmod 700 /mnt/xvdf/home/<username>`
10. `chmod 600 /mnt/xvdf/home/<username>/authorized_keys`
11. Shutdown new instance
12. Detach `Volume A` on new instance
13. Reattach `Volume A` on /dev/sda1 on original instance.
14. Start original instance.

You should be able to login now.